# Is a polygon with irrational internal angles possible?

Tags: geometry, irrational-numbers

I'm aware that the sum of internal angles of an $n$-sided polygon must be $180^\circ(n-2)$, but that doesn't say anything about the individual angles.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly.  You could have a triangle with angles $10\pi^\circ, 20\pi^\circ, (180-30\pi)^\circ$, for example